# How to intersect values over multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Please find below my input/output (desired) :

##### INPTUT :

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
0    A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN    B    C  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN    D  NaN
3  NaN    E  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    F
```

##### OUTPUT (desired) :

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Intersection
0    A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN            A
1  NaN    B    C  NaN  NaN       [B, C]
2  NaN  NaN  NaN    D  NaN            D
3  NaN    E  NaN  NaN  NaN            E
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    F            F
```

I'm trying to add a column `Intersection` that will hold the intersection of all the columns.

My dataset looks exactly like this dataframe (except that he has thousands of rows and dozens of columns) :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Col1': ['A', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'Col2': [np.nan, 'B', np.nan, 'E', np.nan],
        'Col3': [np.nan, 'C', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'Col4': [np.nan, np.nan, 'D', np.nan, np.nan],
        'Col5': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'F']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Do you have any suggestions, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape with remove missing values and aggregate custom function for avoid one element lists:

```
f = lambda x: list(x) if len(x) > 1 else x
df['Intersection'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(f)

print (df)
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Intersection
0    A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN            A
1  NaN    B    C  NaN  NaN       [B, C]
2  NaN  NaN  NaN    D  NaN            D
3  NaN    E  NaN  NaN  NaN            E
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    F            F
```

Or if one element list should be instead scalars use:

```
df['Intersection'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)

print (df)
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Intersection
0    A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN          [A]
1  NaN    B    C  NaN  NaN       [B, C]
2  NaN  NaN  NaN    D  NaN          [D]
3  NaN    E  NaN  NaN  NaN          [E]
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    F          [F]
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. It worked. I have a question: what does it mean a scalar, please ?

Comment: @Stormy - it means `'A'` instead `['A']`